# How to get total hour?

Tags: mysql

```
Name|| day||ActivityDate ||TimeIn  || TimeOut ||
Ade || 20 || 2013-08-20 || 10:06:09 || 18:21:03 ||
Ade || 21 ||2013-08-27  || 11:00:34 || 18:06:56 ||
Ade || 22 || 2013-08-28 || 09:56:29 || 17:59:56 ||
```

This is my query :

```
select 
tot=sum(DATEDIFF(hh ,TimeIn ,TimeOut )) as TotalHourAndMinute
from report
```

And error :

> 1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function
>   'DATEDIFF'

This is my table in datable..
I don't know how to get total hour like TimeOut-TimeIn..

fyi, i have a lot of data in this table.. not only this 3..

i hope you guys clear...

```
Name|| day||ActivityDate ||TimeIn  || TimeOut   || TotalHourAndMinute
Ade || 20 || 2013-08-20 || 10:00:00 || 18:30:00 ||   8.5
Ade || 21 ||2013-08-27  || 11:00:34 || 18:06:56 ||   7.something
Ade || 22 || 2013-08-28 || 09:56:29 || 17:59:56 ||   7.something
```

i want it will be like this..

UPDATE

Comment: which database engine you are using?

Comment: phpmyadmin, hope you can try

Comment: @user2514863 Then I assume you're using MySQL, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're using MySQL the correct format for the function is this:

```
DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
```

More information about `DATEDIFF`, [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff). Also, all available time functions for MySQL are [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

But, if you want to see the difference in hours between two dates, use `TIME_DIFF`.

```
TIMEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
```

And documentation about `TIME_DIFF` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff).

But strictly to your case, you should write your query like this:

```
SELECT tot = sum(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(TimeIn, TimeOut))) AS TotalHourAndMinute
FROM report
```

***UPDATE:***

Now, after updating your question I understand what you want.

The query you need to use is this:

```
SELECT 
      NAME, 
      DAY, 
      ActivityDate, 
      SUM(TIMEDIFF(TimeOut, TimeIn)) as TotalHourAndMinute
FROM REPORT
WHERE (TimeOut IS NOT NULL) AND (TimeIn IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY NAME, DAY, ActivityDate
```

Comment: sorry boss.. i'm still new.. when i put that query, error come out... Unknown column 'tot' in 'field list'

Comment: @user2514863 `tot` should be a NUMERIC variable you previously declared. But if you don't want to store the output in a variable, just use `SELECT sum(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(TimeIn, TimeOut))) AS TotalHourAndMinute
FROM report`

Comment: SELECT sum(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(TimeIn, TimeOut))) AS TotalHourAndMinute
FROM report 

to get totalhour for all record..

Comment: column SUM(HOUR(DATEDIFF(TimeIn,TimeOut))) just output NULL or 0..
simple math, hour=TimeOut-TimeIn
eg: TimeIn=08:00:00
    TimeOut=17:30:00
so  Hour= 9.5

But i can't simple minus like that coz time 1minute=60sec,

Comment: @user2514863 I've switched the order of TimeOut and TimeIn. Try running it now.

Comment: @Radu.. Boss.. almost get it... DATEDIFF change to TIMEDIFF.. but how to get in and minute... the output like this..... eg: TimeIn=08:00:00 TimeOut=17:30:00 so Hour= 9.. the half and hour did't show..

Comment: @user2514863 Test now.

Comment: SELECT  `code` ,  `Name` ,  `day` ,  `ActivityDate` ,  `year` ,  `TimeIn` ,  `TimeOut` , TIMEDIFF( TimeOut, TimeIn ) AS  'FullTime', IF( TIMEDIFF( TimeOut, TimeIn ) >=0,  '+',  '-' ) AS sign, HOUR( TIMEDIFF( TimeOut, TimeIn ) ) AS HOUR , MINUTE( TIMEDIFF( TimeOut, TimeIn ) ) AS 
MINUTE , SECOND( TIMEDIFF( TimeOut, TimeIn ) ) AS 
SECOND 
FROM merapu
GROUP BY Name, 
DAY 
..... that query work like amazing..! thnks boss

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(TimeOut,TimeIn)) AS hour from report;
```

For more information visit [this](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/163-how-to-calculate-the-interval-between-two-dates-or-times-in-mysql/) site.

Comment: i'm sorry boss.. i need 15 reputation.. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you aggregate time values you will get a result in seconds, to convert it back to time you call [`SEC_TO_TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time). This gives you:

```
SELECT
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(TimeOut, TimeIn))) AS TotalHourAndMinute
FROM
    report
```